# Set selected class on navigation buttons/links on JavaScript/Flickity timeline carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, flickity

I am using Flickity to build a history timeline carousel for my client's website. I have built a simplified demo on CodePen showing how it currently works and what needs adjustment.

[CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/mikehermary/pen/oNzbBOq)

The demo was adapted from this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/emVRjv)

The areas that need adjusting are the buttons and having a `is-selected` class added when clicked or tapped by the user.

The following JS includes the code from the pen demo. The problematic code is commented out. If I enable the code, CodePen displays the following error `TypeError: previousSelectedButton is null`

For reference, the HTML template for the finished and working history timeline carousel will be:

```
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel__timeline">
      <ul class="timeline__nav">
        <li class="timeline__item" data-year="1984" >
            <a href="#" id="1984" class="button button--year js-btn--year" data-group=".groupone"><span>1984 to 1988</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline__item" data-year="1989" >
            <a href="#" id="1989" class="button button--year js-btn--year" data-group=".grouptwo">1989 to 1992</a>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline__item" data-year="1993">
            <a href="#" id="1993" class="button button--year js-btn--year" data-group=".groupthree">1993 to 1999</a>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline__item" data-year="2000">
            <a href="#" id="2000" class="button button--year js-btn--year" data-group=".groupfour">2000 to 2002</a>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline__item" data-year="2003">
            <a href="#" id="2003" class="button button--year js-btn--year" data-group=".groupfive">2003 to 2005</a>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline__item" data-year="2006">
            <a href="#" id="2006" class="button button--year js-btn--year" data-group=".groupsix">2006 to 2012</a>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline__item" data-year="2013">
            <a href="#" id="2013" class="button button--year js-btn--year" data-group=".groupseven">2013 to 2020</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel__content">
    {articles category="History" ordering="publish_up ASC" fixhtml="false"}
    <article class="carousel__cell [year-group]">
      [text]
              [year-group]
    </article>
    {/articles}
  </div>
  <div class="carousel__nav">
    <button class="button button--previous js-btn--previous">
        <svg width="18" height="18"><path d="M10.347 1.175L9.455.283a.96.96 0 0 0-1.362 0L.283 8.09a.96.96 0 0 0 0 1.362l7.81 7.81a.96.96 0 0 0 1.362 0l.892-.892a.965.965 0 0 0-.016-1.378L5.49 10.379h11.546c.534 0 .964-.43.964-.964V8.129a.962.962 0 0 0-.964-.964H5.49l4.84-4.612a.958.958 0 0 0 .017-1.378z" fill="#F7F7F7"/></svg>
    </button>
    <button class="button button--next js-btn--next">
        <svg width="18" height="18"><path d="M7.653 1.175l.892-.892a.96.96 0 0 1 1.362 0l7.81 7.806a.96.96 0 0 1 0 1.362l-7.81 7.81a.96.96 0 0 1-1.362 0l-.892-.892a.965.965 0 0 1 .016-1.378l4.841-4.612H.964A.962.962 0 0 1 0 9.415V8.129c0-.534.43-.964.964-.964H12.51L7.67 2.553a.958.958 0 0 1-.017-1.378z" fill="#F7F7F7"/></svg>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code is working on the development site and exhibits the same errors when trying to apply a `is-selected` class to the navigation links.

**JavaScript code**

```
const utils = window.fizzyUIUtils;

const flkty = new Flickity(".carousel", {
  cellAlign: "left",
  contain: true,
  prevNextButtons: false,
  pageDots: false
});

const carouselButtonGroup = document.querySelector(".carousel__buttons");
const carouselButtons = utils.makeArray(carouselButtonGroup.children);

// update buttons on select
// flkty.on( 'select', function() {
//   const previousSelectedButton = carouselButtonGroup.querySelector('.is-selected');
//   const selectedButton = carouselButtonGroup.children[ flkty.selectedIndex ];
//   previousSelectedButton.classList.remove('is-selected');
//   selectedButton.classList.add('is-selected');
// });

carouselButtonGroup.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  // Filter for button clicks
  if (!matchesSelector(event.target, ".button")) {
    return;
  }
  const selector = event.target.getAttribute("data-selector");
  // const index = carouselButtons.indexOf( event.target );
  // flkty.select( index );
  flkty.selectCell(selector);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that there is not default `.carousel__buttons button.is-selected` in your DOM. So at the first call, `carouselButtonGroup.querySelector('.is-selected')` will return `null` because there is no such element yet. You can easily fix that by providing the class `is-selected` to the first button of `.carousel__buttons`:

```html
<div class="carousel__buttons">
  <button class="button is-selected" data-selector=".groupone">
    1984 to 1988
  </button>
  <button class="button" data-selector=".grouptwo">1989-1992</button>
  <button class="button" data-selector=".groupthree">1993-1999</button>
  <button class="button" data-selector=".groupfour">2000-2002</button>
  <button class="button" data-selector=".groupfive">2003-2005</button>
  <button class="button" data-selector=".groupsix">2006-2012</button>
  <button class="button" data-selector=".groupseven">2013-2020</button>
</div>
```

Checkout the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/johannchopin/pen/xxEQqpX).

Answer (score 0):

I see on your [Codepen](https://codepen.io/mikehermary/pen/oNzbBOq) it is still broken because you have repeating DIVs classes in your HTML:

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-cell groupone">
    <p>1984-1988</p>
    <p>Medicine River Wildlife ...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-cell groupone">
    <p>1984-1988</p>
    <p>Wildlife Rehabilitation was ...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-cell grouptwo">
    ...
```

For [flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/) to work right, each div needs to have a unique class name:

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-cell groupone">
    <p>1984-1988</p>
    <p>Medicine River Wildlife ...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-cell grouptwo">
    <p>1984-1988</p>
    <p>Wildlife Rehabilitation was ...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-cell groupthree">
```

and so on...

Comment: Please, add some explanation about your approach